# bootstrap form-horizontal inside a thumbnail create misalignment - responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for an answer to my bootstrap issue working with form layouts. So far, no luck!!

Objective:

Create a registration form that works under tablets/desktop/iphone

Issue:

I used thumbnail since it has all the css I need to box around the form. I used form-horizontal. The layout on the desktop is OK, everything is aligned. Until I view it on the ipad (portrait): picture below;

-- Sorry, this is my first time posting so I dont have enough points to post images. it looks something like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21743176/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-26%20at%203.26.13%20PM.png

The first input box is using span6 whereas the rest are not. Even with span6, the controls (label and input) are not centred. I can reduce the width of the label to be whatever so that it would align to the centre but that would mean adding specific @media width etc.

Here is a snap shot of my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="section">
                <ul class="thumbnails row">
                    <li class="span6 offset3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <legend><h5><i class="icon-pencil"></i>    Sign-up</h5></legend>
                                    <form action="signup/user_signup" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="signup-form">
                                        <fieldset>
                                        <div class="control-group" id="Name">
                                            <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="text" name="inputName" class="span6"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group" id="Email">
                                            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="text" name="inputEmail" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group" id="Username">
                                            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">Username</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="text" name="inputUsername" id="inputUsername"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group" id="Pwd">
                                            <label for="inputPwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="password" name="inputPwd" id="inputPwd"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="control-group" id="CPwd">
                                            <label for="inputConfirmPwd" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="password" name="inputConfirmPwd" id="inputConfirmPwd"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group" id="TNC">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <label class="checkbox">
                                                    <input type="checkbox"> Accept terms and conditions
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <button type="cancel" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Questions:

When do I use form-inline or form-horizontal. Some say that to use form-horizontal you must have a wide page.. not sure if it is true.

So, can you please let me know if my html/approach is no good?

Comment: As you have the CSS of this special form, and what size is your page width.

Comment: Using the responsive css.. so I guess 1170px

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yR7Ap/77/)

I found a couple of examples of using width: 100% to force the text boxes to stay within their container.  It centers on large pages but on tables the well expands to the edges and on the phone it will switch from form-horizontal to form-inline.

```
.my-input
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 0 !important;
}

 <input class="my-input" maxlength="80" type="text" name="inputName"  />
```